# Entity Framework async operation takes ten times as long to complete

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, async-await

I’ve got an MVC site that’s using Entity Framework 6 to handle the database, and I’ve been experimenting with changing it so that everything runs as async controllers and calls to the database are ran as their async counterparts (eg. ToListAsync() instead of ToList())

The problem I’m having is that simply changing my queries to async has caused them to be incredibly slow.

The following code gets a collection of "Album" objects from my data context and is translated to a fairly simple database join:

```cs
// Get the albums
var albums = await this.context.Albums
    .Where(x => x.Artist.ID == artist.ID)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Here’s the SQL that’s created:

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[URL] AS [URL], 
[Extent1].[ASIN] AS [ASIN], 
[Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
[Extent1].[ReleaseDate] AS [ReleaseDate], 
[Extent1].[AccurateDay] AS [AccurateDay], 
[Extent1].[AccurateMonth] AS [AccurateMonth], 
[Extent1].[Type] AS [Type], 
[Extent1].[Tracks] AS [Tracks], 
[Extent1].[MainCredits] AS [MainCredits], 
[Extent1].[SupportingCredits] AS [SupportingCredits], 
[Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Extent1].[Image] AS [Image], 
[Extent1].[HasImage] AS [HasImage], 
[Extent1].[Created] AS [Created], 
[Extent1].[Artist_ID] AS [Artist_ID]
FROM [dbo].[Albums] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Artist_ID] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=134
```

As things go, it’s not a massively complicated query, but it’s taking almost 6 seconds for SQL server to run it. SQL Server Profiler reports it as taking 5742ms to complete.

If I change my code to:

```cs
// Get the albums
var albums = this.context.Albums
    .Where(x => x.Artist.ID == artist.ID)
    .ToList();
```

Then the exact same SQL is generated, yet this runs in just 474ms according to SQL Server Profiler.

The database has around 3500 rows in the "Albums" table, which isn’t really very many, and has an index on the "Artist_ID" column, so it should be pretty fast.

I know that async has overheads, but making things go ten times slower seems a bit steep to me! Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: it does not look right to me. If you execute the same query with the same data, the execution time reported by SQL Server Profiler should be more or less the same because async is what happens in c#, not Sql. Sql server is even not aware that your c# code is async

Comment: when you run your generated query the first time, it may take a bit longer to compile the query (build execution plan,...), from the second time, the same query may be faster (Sql server caches the query), but there should not be too much different.

Comment: [EF should be pretty fast with async](http://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/analysis-of-entity-framework-6-async-performance/). How many times did you measure this query? Are you sure the difference is because of async/await and not because of some external factor? As @KhanhTO mentioned, the times in the profiler should be in the exact same ballpark I feel.

Comment: I’ve ran it multiple times, and it’s always around 6 seconds when using async, and around 0.5 seconds when running synchronously. It’s really weird—as you say, it’s being run in SQL Server at that point, so it shouldn’t make a difference, but it does and I have no idea why.

Comment: You need to determine what's slow. Run the query in an infinite loop. Pause the debugger 10 times. Where does it stop most often? Post the stack including external code.

Comment: Are you certain both versions of your query include "exec sp_executesql"? For me, that's got to be a bit of the slowdown. EF shouldn't need to execute the SQL through the evaluator like that.

Comment: It looks like the problem is to do with the Image property, which I’d totally forgotten about. It’s a VARBINARY(MAX) column, so is bound to cause slowness, but it’s still a bit weird that the slowness only becomes an issue running async. I’ve restructured my database so that the images are now part of a linked table and everything is far faster now.

Comment: The problem might be that EF is issuing tons of async reads to ADO.NET to retrieve all those bytes and rows. That way the overhead is magnified. Since you did not perform the measurement I asked we will never know. Problem seems to be solved.

Answer (score 356, accepted):

I found this question very interesting, especially since I'm using `async` everywhere with Ado.Net and EF 6. I was hoping someone to give an explanation for this question, but it doesn't happened. So I tried to reproduce this problem on my side. I hope some of you will find this interesting.

First good news : I reproduced it  :) And the difference is enormous. With a factor 8 ...

[image: first results]

First I was suspecting something dealing with [`CommandBehavior`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.commandbehavior), since [I read an interesting article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/adonet/using-sqldatareaders-new-async-methods-in-net-4-5) about `async` with Ado, saying this :

"Since non-sequential access mode has to store the data for the entire row, it can cause issues if you are reading a large column from the server (such as varbinary(MAX), varchar(MAX), nvarchar(MAX) or XML)."

I was suspecting `ToList()` calls to be `CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess` and async ones to be `CommandBehavior.Default` (non-sequential, which can cause issues). So I downloaded EF6's sources, and put breakpoints everywhere (where `CommandBehavior` where used, of course).

Result : **nothing**. All the calls are made with `CommandBehavior.Default` .... So I tried to step into EF code to understand what happens... and.. ooouch... I never see such a delegating code, everything seems lazy executed...

So I tried to do some profiling to understand what happens...

And I think I have something...

Here's the model to create the table I benchmarked, with 3500 lines inside of it, and 256 Kb random data in each `varbinary(MAX)`. (EF 6.1 - CodeFirst - [CodePlex](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest)) :

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public TestContext()
        : base(@"Server=(localdb)\\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=BENCH") // Local instance
    {
    }
    public DbSet<TestItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class TestItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] BinaryData { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the code I used to create the test data, and benchmark EF.

```
using (TestContext db = new TestContext())
{
    if (!db.Items.Any())
    {
        foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(0, 3500)) // Fill 3500 lines
        {
            byte[] dummyData = new byte[1 << 18];  // with 256 Kbyte
            new Random().NextBytes(dummyData);
            db.Items.Add(new TestItem() { Name = i.ToString(), BinaryData = dummyData });
        }
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}

using (TestContext db = new TestContext())  // EF Warm Up
{
    var warmItUp = db.Items.FirstOrDefault();
    warmItUp = await db.Items.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}

Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
using (TestContext db = new TestContext())
{
    watch.Start();
    var testRegular = db.Items.ToList();
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("non async : " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}

using (TestContext db = new TestContext())
{
    watch.Restart();
    var testAsync = await db.Items.ToListAsync();
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("async : " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(CS))
{
    await connection.OpenAsync();
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, Name, BinaryData FROM dbo.TestItems", connection))
    {
        watch.Restart();
        List<TestItem> itemsWithAdo = new List<TestItem>();
        var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);
        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
        {
            var item = new TestItem();
            item.ID = (int)reader[0];
            item.Name = (String)reader[1];
            item.BinaryData = (byte[])reader[2];
            itemsWithAdo.Add(item);
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("ExecuteReaderAsync SequentialAccess : " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(CS))
{
    await connection.OpenAsync();
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, Name, BinaryData FROM dbo.TestItems", connection))
    {
        watch.Restart();
        List<TestItem> itemsWithAdo = new List<TestItem>();
        var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.Default);
        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
        {
            var item = new TestItem();
            item.ID = (int)reader[0];
            item.Name = (String)reader[1];
            item.BinaryData = (byte[])reader[2];
            itemsWithAdo.Add(item);
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("ExecuteReaderAsync Default : " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(CS))
{
    await connection.OpenAsync();
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, Name, BinaryData FROM dbo.TestItems", connection))
    {
        watch.Restart();
        List<TestItem> itemsWithAdo = new List<TestItem>();
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var item = new TestItem();
            item.ID = (int)reader[0];
            item.Name = (String)reader[1];
            item.BinaryData = (byte[])reader[2];
            itemsWithAdo.Add(item);
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("ExecuteReader SequentialAccess : " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(CS))
{
    await connection.OpenAsync();
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, Name, BinaryData FROM dbo.TestItems", connection))
    {
        watch.Restart();
        List<TestItem> itemsWithAdo = new List<TestItem>();
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default);
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var item = new TestItem();
            item.ID = (int)reader[0];
            item.Name = (String)reader[1];
            item.BinaryData = (byte[])reader[2];
            itemsWithAdo.Add(item);
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("ExecuteReader Default : " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

For the regular EF call (`.ToList()`), the profiling seems "normal" and is easy to read :

[image: ToList trace]

Here we find the 8.4 seconds we have with the Stopwatch (profiling slow downs the perfs). We also find HitCount = 3500 along the call path, which is consistent with the 3500 lines in the test. On the TDS parser side, things start to became worse since we read 118 353 calls on `TryReadByteArray()` method, which is were the buffering loop occurs. (an average 33.8 calls for each `byte[]` of 256kb)

For the `async` case, it's really really different.... First, the `.ToListAsync()` call is scheduled on the ThreadPool, and then awaited. Nothing amazing here. But, now, here's the `async` hell on the ThreadPool :

[image: ToListAsync hell]

First, in the first case we were having just 3500 hit counts along the full call path, here we have 118 371. Moreover, you have to imagine all the synchronization calls I didn't put on the screenshoot...

Second, in the first case, we were having "just 118 353" calls to the `TryReadByteArray()` method, here we have 2 050 210 calls ! It's 17 times more... (on a test with large 1Mb array, it's 160 times more)

Moreover there are :

- 120 000 `Task` instances created
- 727 519 `Interlocked` calls
- 290 569 `Monitor` calls
- 98 283 `ExecutionContext` instances, with 264 481 Captures
- 208 733 `SpinLock` calls

My guess is the buffering is made in an async way (and not a good one), with parallel Tasks trying to read data from the TDS. Too many Task are created just to parse the binary data.

As a preliminary conclusion, we can say Async is great, EF6 is great, but EF6's usages of async in it's current implementation adds a major overhead, on the performance side, the Threading side, and the CPU side (12% CPU usage in the `ToList()` case and 20% in the `ToListAsync` case for a 8 to 10 times longer work... I run it on an old i7 920).

While doings some tests, I was thinking about [this article again](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/adonet/using-sqldatareaders-new-async-methods-in-net-4-5) and I notice something I miss :

"For the new asynchronous methods in .Net 4.5, their behavior is exactly the same as with the synchronous methods, except for one notable exception: ReadAsync in non-sequential mode."

What ?!!!

So I extend my benchmarks to include Ado.Net in regular / async call, and with `CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess` / `CommandBehavior.Default`, and here's a big surprise ! :

[image: with ado]

We have the exact same behavior with Ado.Net !!! Facepalm...

**My definitive conclusion is** : there's a bug in EF 6 implementation. It should toggle the `CommandBehavior` to `SequentialAccess` when an async call is made over a table containing a `binary(max)` column. The problem of creating too many Task, slowing down the process, is on the Ado.Net side. The EF problem is that it doesn't use Ado.Net as it should.

Now you know instead of using the EF6 async methods, you would better have to call EF in a regular non-async way, and then use a `TaskCompletionSource<T>` to return the result in an async way.

Note 1 :  I edited my post because of a shameful error.... I've done my first test over the network, not locally, and the limited bandwidth have distorted the results. Here are the updated results.

Note 2 : I didn't extends my test to other uses cases (ex : `nvarchar(max)` with a lot of data), but there are chances the same behavior happens.

Note 3 : Something usual for the `ToList()` case, is the 12% CPU (1/8 of my CPU = 1 logical core). Something unusual is the maximum 20% for the `ToListAsync()` case, as if the Scheduler could not use all the Treads. It's probably due to the too many Task created, or maybe a bottleneck in TDS parser, I don't know...

Comment: Good research. I wonder if you could try two more things: 1) Call `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(500, 500)` at the very beginning of all your tests; 2) Use `ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere use use `await`. See if that makes any difference.

Comment: I did the test with just ConfigureAwait(), then with SetMinThreads(), and it's the same order of magnitude.

Comment: Amazing effort! I’m glad that you were able to reproduce what I was seeing, and you’ve essentially come to the same conclusion that it’s the varbinary(max) that’s causing the issue—well, that combined with a potential bug in EF6. I solved it by moving the varbinary column to another linked table, but a better way would be for EF6 to do the right thing in the first place! Thanks for looking into this in so much detail.

Comment: I opened an issue on codeplex, hope they will do something about it. https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2686

Comment: Could you post/link the benchmark code you used for `ExecuteReader`?

Comment: @JeroenMostert : I added the methods in the post

Comment: Thanks. The perf problem is within ADO.NET, but I don't quite have a handle yet on where exactly it's coming from. There is no technical reason why `ReadAsync`/`CommandBehavior.Default` couldn't be as efficient as `Read`/`CommandBehavior.Default`; I suspect it's in the way the async code was written that does not take reading huge binary columns into account. The 120.000 tasks should not be the problem (they're very short lived and cause no GC pressure) -- you should see those even with `ReadAsync`/`CommandBehavior.Sequential`. You *are* reading about 1 GB async, that's a lot of packets.

Comment: @DanielPaoliello, the author of the article I mention, and an Ado dev @ Microsoft, said "ReadAsync in default command behavior buffers the entire row into memory, so subsequent async calls to read column values is a waste of CPU". It's perhaps a design problem with the way TDS parsing is made in an async way. I would really like he posted a developed explanation, but he doesn't seems active on community since last year. I found another post of him about the same problem here : https://dpaoliello.wordpress.com/2014/04/22/improving-async-performance-for-sqldatareader/

Comment: I opened an issue on new EF code repo hosted on github: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/88

Comment: Sadly the issue on GitHub has been closed with the advice to not use async with varbinary. In theory varbinary should be the case where async makes most sense as the thread will be blocked longer while the file is transmitted. So what do we do now if we want to save binary data in the DB?

Comment: Anyone know if this is still an issue in EF Core? I've been unable to find any information or benchmarks.

Comment: @AndrewLewis I have no science behind it, but I'm having repeated connection pool timeouts with EF Core where the two queries causing issues are `.ToListAsync()` and `.CountAsync()`...  To anybody else finding this comment thread, [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12428235/382456) may help.  Godspeed.

Comment: Just came across this in Entity Framework Core 3. When reading a 100Mb file, in sync it takes around 1 second (very approx), when async it takes a few minutes

Comment: It still exists in Ef Core and I couldn,t overcome that problem except using none-async methods

Comment: I wanted to chime in and verify Note 2 - that this behavior can be observed with a sufficiently large `nvarchar(max)` field.

Comment: update for 2021-08-20: 
I ran the code above with dotnet 4.8 and EF 6.4.4 and added dapper as a comparison.
I get the "bad" performance on all metrics!

Answer (score 14):

Because I got a link to this question a couple of days ago I decided to post a small update. I was able to reproduce the results of the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28619983) using the, currently, newest version of EF (6.4.0) and .NET Framework 4.7.2. Surprisingly this problem never got improved upon.

```
.NET Framework 4.7.2 | EF 6.4.0 (Values in ms. Average of 10 runs)

non async : 3016
async : 20415
ExecuteReaderAsync SequentialAccess : 2780
ExecuteReaderAsync Default : 21061
ExecuteReader SequentialAccess : 3467
ExecuteReader Default : 3074
```

This begged the question: Is there an improvement in dotnet core?

I copied the code from the original answer to a new dotnet core 3.1.3 project and added EF Core 3.1.3. The results are:

```
dotnet core 3.1.3 | EF Core 3.1.3 (Values in ms. Average of 10 runs)

non async : 2780
async : 6563
ExecuteReaderAsync SequentialAccess : 2593
ExecuteReaderAsync Default : 6679
ExecuteReader SequentialAccess : 2668
ExecuteReader Default : 2315
```

Surprisingly there's a lot of improvement. There's still seems some time lag because the threadpool gets called but it's about 3 times faster than the .NET Framework implementation.

I hope this answer helps other people that get send this way in the future.

Answer (score 2):

**There is a solution that allows using async without sacrificing performance, tested with EF Core and MS SQL database.**

First you will need to make a wrapper for `DBDataReader`:

1. Its `ReadAsync` method should read the whole row, storing each column's value in a buffer.
2. Its `GetXyz` methods should get the value from the aforementioned buffer.
3. Optionally, use `GetBytes` + `Encoding.GetString` instead of `GetString`. For my use cases (16KB text column per row), it resulted in significant speedup both for sync and async.
4. Optionally, adjust the Packet Size of your connection string. For my use cases, a value of 32767 resulted in significant speedup both for sync and async.

You can now make a `DbCommandInterceptor`, intercepting `ReaderExecutingAsync` to create a `DBDataReader` with sequential access, wrapped by the aforementioned wrapper.

EF Core will try to access fields in a non-sequential manner - that is why the wrapper must read and buffer the whole row first.

Here is an example implementation (intercepts both async and sync):

```
/// <summary>
/// This interceptor optimizes a <see cref="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext"/> for
/// accessing large columns (text, ntext, varchar(max) and nvarchar(max)). It enables the
/// <see cref="CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess"/> option and uses an optimized method
/// for converting large text columns into <see cref="string"/> objects.
/// </summary>
public class ExampleDbCommandInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
{
    public async override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>> ReaderExecutingAsync(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var behavior = CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess;

        var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(behavior, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        var wrapper = await DbDataReaderOptimizedWrapper.CreateAsync(reader, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>.SuppressWithResult(wrapper);
    }

    public override InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result)
    {
        var behavior = CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess;

        var reader = command.ExecuteReader(behavior);

        var wrapper = DbDataReaderOptimizedWrapper.Create(reader);

        return InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>.SuppressWithResult(wrapper);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This wrapper caches the values of accessed columns of each row, allowing non-sequential access
    /// even when <see cref="CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess"/> is specified. It enables using this option it with EF Core.
    /// In addition, it provides an optimized method for reading text, ntext, varchar(max) and nvarchar(max) columns.
    /// All in all, it speeds up database operations reading from large text columns.
    /// </summary>
    sealed class DbDataReaderOptimizedWrapper : DbDataReader
    {
        readonly DbDataReader reader;
        readonly DbColumn[] schema;

        readonly object[] cache;
        readonly Func<object>[] materializers;

        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImpl(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        private T Get<T>(int ordinal)
        {
            if (cache[ordinal] != DBNull.Value) return (T)cache[ordinal];

            return (T)(object)null; // this line will throw an exception if T is not a reference type (class), otherwise it will return null
        }

        private DbDataReaderOptimizedWrapper(DbDataReader reader, IEnumerable<DbColumn> schema)
        {
            this.reader = reader;
            this.schema = schema.OrderBy(x => x.ColumnOrdinal).ToArray();

            cache = new object[this.schema.Length];


            byte[] stringGetterBuffer = null;

            string stringGetter(int i)
            {
                var dbColumn = this.schema[i];

                // Using GetBytes instead of GetString is much faster, but only works for text, ntext, varchar(max) and nvarchar(max)
                if (dbColumn.ColumnSize < int.MaxValue) return reader.GetString(i);

                if (stringGetterBuffer == null) stringGetterBuffer = new byte[32 * 1024];

                var totalRead = 0;

                while (true)
                {
                    var offset = totalRead;

                    totalRead += (int)reader.GetBytes(i, offset, stringGetterBuffer, offset, stringGetterBuffer.Length - offset);

                    if (totalRead < stringGetterBuffer.Length) break;

                    const int maxBufferSize = int.MaxValue / 2;

                    if (stringGetterBuffer.Length >= maxBufferSize)

                        throw new OutOfMemoryException($"{nameof(DbDataReaderOptimizedWrapper)}.{nameof(GetString)} cannot load column '{GetName(i)}' because it contains a string longer than {maxBufferSize} bytes.");

                    Array.Resize(ref stringGetterBuffer, 2 * stringGetterBuffer.Length);
                }

                var c = dbColumn.DataTypeName[0];

                var encoding = (c is 'N' or 'n') ? Encoding.Unicode : Encoding.ASCII;

                return encoding.GetString(stringGetterBuffer.AsSpan(0, totalRead));
            }

            var dict = new Dictionary<Type, Func<DbColumn, int, Func<object>>>
            {
                [typeof(bool)] = (column, index) => () => reader.GetBoolean(index),
                [typeof(byte)] = (column, index) => () => reader.GetByte(index),
                [typeof(char)] = (column, index) => () => reader.GetChar(index),

                [typeof(short)] = (column, index) => () => reader.GetInt16(index),
                [typeof(int)] = (column, index) => () => reader.GetInt32(index),
                [typeof(long)] = (column, index) => () => reader.GetInt64(index),

                [typeof(float)] = (column, index) => () => reader.GetFloat(index),
                [typeof(double)] = (column, index) => () => reader.GetDouble(index),
                [typeof(decimal)] = (column, index) => () => reader.GetDecimal(index),

                [typeof(DateTime)] = (column, index) => () => reader.GetDateTime(index),
                [typeof(Guid)] = (column, index) => () => reader.GetGuid(index),

                [typeof(string)] = (column, index) => () => stringGetter(index),
            };

            materializers = schema.Select((column, index) => dict[column.DataType](column, index)).ToArray();
        }

        public static DbDataReaderOptimizedWrapper Create(DbDataReader reader) 

            => new DbDataReaderOptimizedWrapper(reader, reader.GetColumnSchema());

        public static async ValueTask<DbDataReaderOptimizedWrapper> CreateAsync(DbDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
            
            => new DbDataReaderOptimizedWrapper(reader, await reader.GetColumnSchemaAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false));

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) => reader.Dispose();

        public async override ValueTask DisposeAsync() => await reader.DisposeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);


        public override object this[int ordinal] => Get<object>(ordinal);
        public override object this[string name] => Get<object>(GetOrdinal(name));

        public override int Depth => reader.Depth;

        public override int FieldCount => reader.FieldCount;

        public override bool HasRows => reader.HasRows;

        public override bool IsClosed => reader.IsClosed;

        public override int RecordsAffected => reader.RecordsAffected;

        public override int VisibleFieldCount => reader.VisibleFieldCount;


        public override bool GetBoolean(int ordinal) => Get<bool>(ordinal);

        public override byte GetByte(int ordinal) => Get<byte>(ordinal);

        public override long GetBytes(int ordinal, long dataOffset, byte[] buffer, int bufferOffset, int length) => throw new NotSupportedException();

        public override char GetChar(int ordinal) => Get<char>(ordinal);

        public override long GetChars(int ordinal, long dataOffset, char[] buffer, int bufferOffset, int length) => throw new NotSupportedException();

        public override string GetDataTypeName(int ordinal) => reader.GetDataTypeName(ordinal);

        public override DateTime GetDateTime(int ordinal) => Get<DateTime>(ordinal);

        public override decimal GetDecimal(int ordinal) => Get<decimal>(ordinal);

        public override double GetDouble(int ordinal) => Get<double>(ordinal);

        public override IEnumerator GetEnumerator() => reader.GetEnumerator();

        public override Type GetFieldType(int ordinal) => reader.GetFieldType(ordinal);

        public override float GetFloat(int ordinal) => Get<float>(ordinal);

        public override Guid GetGuid(int ordinal) => Get<Guid>(ordinal);

        public override short GetInt16(int ordinal) => Get<short>(ordinal);

        public override int GetInt32(int ordinal) => Get<int>(ordinal);

        public override long GetInt64(int ordinal) => Get<long>(ordinal);

        public override string GetName(int ordinal) => reader.GetName(ordinal);

        public override int GetOrdinal(string name) => reader.GetOrdinal(name);

        public override string GetString(int ordinal) => Get<string>(ordinal);

        public override object GetValue(int ordinal) => Get<object>(ordinal);

        public override int GetValues(object[] values)
        {
            var min = Math.Min(cache.Length, values.Length);

            Array.Copy(cache, values, min);

            return min;
        }

        public override bool IsDBNull(int ordinal) => Convert.IsDBNull(cache[ordinal]);

        public override bool NextResult() => reader.NextResult();

        public override bool Read()
        {
            Array.Clear(cache, 0, cache.Length);

            if (reader.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < cache.Length; ++i)
                {
                    if ((schema[i].AllowDBNull ?? true) && reader.IsDBNull(i)) 
                        
                        cache[i] = DBNull.Value;

                    else cache[i] = materializers[i]();
                }

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public override void Close() => reader.Close();

        public async override Task CloseAsync() => await reader.CloseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        public override DataTable GetSchemaTable() => reader.GetSchemaTable();

        public async override Task<DataTable> GetSchemaTableAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) => await reader.GetSchemaTableAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        public async override Task<ReadOnlyCollection<DbColumn>> GetColumnSchemaAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) => await reader.GetColumnSchemaAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        public async override Task<bool> NextResultAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) => await reader.NextResultAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        public async override Task<bool> ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Array.Clear(cache, 0, cache.Length);

            if (await reader.ReadAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < cache.Length; ++i)
                {
                    if ((schema[i].AllowDBNull ?? true) && await reader.IsDBNullAsync(i, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false)) 
                        
                        cache[i] = DBNull.Value;

                    else cache[i] = materializers[i]();
                }

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I can't provide a benchmark right now, hopefully someone will do so in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the answer given by @rducom. This issue is still present in `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.0`

The blocking part is actually `SqlClient` and the recommended workaround by @AndriySvyryd that works on the EF core project is:

> Don't use VARCHAR(MAX) or don't use async queries.

This happened to me when reading a large JSON object and Image (binary) data with `async` queries.

Links:

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18571#issuecomment-545992812

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18571

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/885

https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/245

https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/593

Answer (score 1):

The quickfix for me was wrapping the the call in a task and just use the synchronous method instead.

It isn't a general fix it all solution, but at with small aggregates it can be confined to a small part of the application.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).