# Entity Framework 6 and Async() Performance

Tags: entity-framework, asynchronous

i have a question about Entity Framework 6 and ToListAsync()/ToList().

if i have a little amount of data (around 1000 rows) i have noticed that ToListAsync() is faster than ToList().

But if i have a huge amount of data (around 600.000 rows) ToList() is faster than ToListAsync().

Here you can fine the code, someone can explain me why?.

```
//SharedAnagra contains around 1000 rows
static List<SharedAnagra> GetSharedAnagraList()
{
    using (Intranet2k3Entities intranet2K3Entities = new Intranet2k3Entities())
    {
        List<SharedAnagra> listaSharedAnagras = (from a in intranet2K3Entities.sharedAnagra
                                                 select new SharedAnagra
                                                 {
                                                     AnagraActive = a.AnagraActive,
                                                     AnagraId = a.AnagraID,
                                                     AnagraName = a.AnagraName,
                                                     OfficeId = a.OfficeID
                                                 }).ToList();

        return listaSharedAnagras;
    }
}

static async Task<List<SharedAnagra>> GetSharedAnagraListAsync()
{
    using (Intranet2k3Entities intranet2K3Entities = new Intranet2k3Entities())
    {
        List<SharedAnagra> listaSharedAnagras = await (from a in intranet2K3Entities.sharedAnagra
                                                       select new SharedAnagra
                                                       {
                                                           AnagraActive = a.AnagraActive,
                                                           AnagraId = a.AnagraID,
                                                           AnagraName = a.AnagraName,
                                                           OfficeId = a.OfficeID
                                                       }).ToListAsync();

        return listaSharedAnagras;
    }
} 


//sharedAnagraNDGClienti contains 950000 rows
static List<SharedAnagraNdgClienti> ListaSharedNdgClienti()
{
    using (Intranet2k3Entities intranet2K3Entities = new Intranet2k3Entities())
    {
        List<SharedAnagraNdgClienti> lista = (from a in intranet2K3Entities.sharedAnagraNDGClienti
                                              select new SharedAnagraNdgClienti
                                              {
                                                  Cm = a.CM,
                                                  CodFisc = a.CodFisc,
                                                  Cognome = a.Cognome,
                                                  Descrizione = a.Descrizione,
                                                  FilialePrevalente = a.Filiale_Prevalente,
                                                  Ndg = a.NDG,
                                                  Nome = a.Nome,
                                                  Telefono = a.Telefono,
                                                  Tipologia = a.Tipologia,
                                                  Trae = a.TRAE,
                                                  Tsae = a.TSAE
                                              }).AsNoTracking().ToList();

        return lista;
    }
}

static async Task<List<SharedAnagraNdgClienti>> GetIssueTypeByIdAsync()
{
    List<SharedAnagraNdgClienti> listaSharedAnagraNdgClienti;

    using (Intranet2k3Entities intranet2K3Entities = new Intranet2k3Entities())
    {
        listaSharedAnagraNdgClienti = await (from a in intranet2K3Entities.sharedAnagraNDGClienti
                                             select new SharedAnagraNdgClienti
                                             {
                                                 Cm = a.CM,
                                                 CodFisc = a.CodFisc,
                                                 Cognome = a.Cognome,
                                                 Descrizione = a.Descrizione,
                                                 FilialePrevalente = a.Filiale_Prevalente,
                                                 Ndg = a.NDG,
                                                 Nome = a.Nome,
                                                 Telefono = a.Telefono,
                                                 Tipologia = a.Tipologia,
                                                 Trae = a.TRAE,
                                                 Tsae = a.TSAE
                                             }).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
    }

    return listaSharedAnagraNdgClienti;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not a problem of your query.This is an issue of EF 6+ framework itself.I personally didn't do any R&D about `Asyn vc Sync`.But I have found out some useful posts about that.Hope that will help to you.

*When to really use async ?*

> In most applications using async will have no noticeable benefits and
>   even could be detrimental. Use tests, profiling and common sense to
>   measure the impact of async in your particular scenario before
>   committing to it.

Here is that article : [**Async Query & Save (EF6 onwards)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819165.aspx)

And here is the Great research done by one of the Stackoveflow user.You can read that too.Great one.

[**Entity Framework async operation takes ten times as long to complete**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543293/entity-framework-async-operation-takes-ten-times-as-long-to-complete)