# Entity Framework 6 Performance of Async methods vs Sync methods

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous

I've modified a Github project to test for some more Entity Framework related ways of doing queries.

[Link](https://github.com/Skywanker/ORMBenchmarksTest)

Models:

```
[Table("Player")]
public partial class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public int TeamId { get; set; }

    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
}

[Table("Team")]
public partial class Team
{
    public Team()
    {
        Players = new HashSet<Player>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime FoundingDate { get; set; }

    public int SportId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }

    public virtual Sport Sport { get; set; }
}

[Table("Sport")]
public partial class Sport
{
    public Sport()
    {
        Teams = new HashSet<Team>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }
}
```

What i am testing for is these things:

**EF "Sync" - FirstOrDefault() and ToList()**

```
context.Players.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

context.Players.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.TeamId == teamId).ToList();

context.Teams.AsNoTracking().Include(x => x.Players).Where(x => x.SportId == sportId).ToList();
```

**EF "Async" - FirstOrDefaultAsync() and ToListAsync()**

```
await context.Players.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

await context.Players.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.TeamId == teamId).ToListAsync();

await context.Teams.AsNoTracking().Include(x => x.Players).Where(x => x.SportId == sportId).ToListAsync();
```

**EF "Sync" with Select into DTO objects**

```
context.Players.Select(p => new PlayerDTO()
                {
                    Id = p.Id,
                    FirstName = p.FirstName,
                    DateOfBirth = p.DateOfBirth,
                    LastName = p.LastName,
                    TeamId = p.TeamId

                }).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

context.Players.Where(x => x.TeamId == teamId).Select(p => new PlayerDTO()
                {
                    Id = p.Id,
                    FirstName = p.FirstName,
                    DateOfBirth = p.DateOfBirth,
                    LastName = p.LastName,
                    TeamId = p.TeamId
                }).ToList();

context.Teams.Where(x => x.SportId == sportId).Select(t => new TeamDTO()
                    {
                        Id = t.Id,
                        FoundingDate = t.FoundingDate,
                        Name = t.Name,
                        SportId = t.SportId,
                        Players = t.Players.Select(p => new PlayerDTO()
                        {
                            Id = p.Id,
                            FirstName = p.FirstName,
                            DateOfBirth = p.DateOfBirth,
                            LastName = p.LastName,
                            TeamId = p.TeamId
                        }).ToList()
                    }).ToList();
```

**EF "Async" with Select into DTO objects**

```
await context.Players.Select(p => new PlayerDTO()
                {
                    Id = p.Id,
                    FirstName = p.FirstName,
                    DateOfBirth = p.DateOfBirth,
                    LastName = p.LastName,
                    TeamId = p.TeamId

                }).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

 await context.Players.Where(x => x.TeamId == teamId).Select(p => new PlayerDTO()
                {
                    Id = p.Id,
                    FirstName = p.FirstName,
                    DateOfBirth = p.DateOfBirth,
                    LastName = p.LastName,
                    TeamId = p.TeamId
                }).ToListAsync();

await context.Teams.Where(x => x.SportId == sportId).Select(t => new TeamDTO()
                {
                    Id = t.Id,
                    FoundingDate = t.FoundingDate,
                    Name = t.Name,
                    SportId = t.SportId,
                    Players = t.Players.Select(p => new PlayerDTO()
                    {
                        Id = p.Id,
                        FirstName = p.FirstName,
                        DateOfBirth = p.DateOfBirth,
                        LastName = p.LastName,
                        TeamId = p.TeamId
                    }).ToList()
                }).ToListAsync();
```

my result are quite troublesome i think. mostly because MS is promoting the Async part of EF alot.

My results: (in miliseconds)

Number of Sports: 8, Number of Teams: 30, Number of Players: 100

```
EntityFrameworkAsyncDTO Results
Run #   Player by ID            Players per Team                Teams per Sport
0               1,46                    3,47                    35,88
1               1,04                    3                       33
2               1,02                    3,3                     33,75
3               1,03                    3                       31,75
4               1,1                     3,27                    31,38
EntityFrameworkAsync Results
Run #   Player by ID            Players per Team                Teams per Sport
0               1,17                    3,53                    57
1               1,01                    3                       48,62
2               0,99                    3,03                    47,88
3               1,02                    3,07                    51
4               1                       3,03                    48,88
EntityFrameworkDTO Results
Run #   Player by ID            Players per Team                Teams per Sport
0               0,02                    3                       13,25
1               0,01                    2,8                     13,12
2               0,15                    2,97                    13,25
3               0,02                    2,9                     13,25
4               0,05                    2,8                     13,12
EntityFramework Results
Run #   Player by ID            Players per Team                Teams per Sport
0               0,01                    2,27                    28,38
1               0,01                    2,4                     28,25
2               0                       2,13                    28,5
3               0,01                    2,17                    27,5
4               0,01                    2,13                    29
ADONET Results
Run #   Player by ID            Players per Team                Teams per Sport
0               0                       2,03                    11,75
1               0                       2                       12,62
2               0                       2                       11,38
3               0                       2                       12,38
4               0                       2                       11,25
```

/EDIT I've added the ADO.NET times to the result list as a reference.

My question is: Am i doing something wrong with my queries since the load times are so different ?

*In a real world system i have running, i have changed out ALL my Async DB calls to Sync calls, and for what i can see in my statistics the system are seeing a ~50% speed increase of DB calls. This is a system with 100-120 cuncurrent users connected via SignalR, it is very DB heavy.*

Comment: You want to compare First vs FirstAsync and Find vs FindAsync. First and Find doing quite some different amount of work.

Comment: Also, `Async` is not "faster". It adds a lot of overhead. But it allows to use time when you are waiting for say network communication.

Comment: I do know that the Async/Await has an overhead, but i would not think that my SQL calls via EF would be 2-4 times slower.

Comment: i know Find is not the same as First. I've changed the code to use First instead of Find

Comment: Async can also become way worse when using large column such as (varbinary(MAX), varchar(MAX), nvarchar(MAX) or XML) see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543293/entity-framework-async-operation-takes-ten-times-as-long-to-complete/28619983#28619983

Answer (score 3):

I think [this article](http://apmblog.dynatrace.com/2014/10/09/behind-net-4-5-async-scene-performance-impact-asynchronous-programming-c/) explains it in details.

Async is not faster and adds a lot of overhead on top of normal "sync" code. But it allows to use resources better in cases when you are wasting your time waiting (e g high latency on network connection etc)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other contributors, if you run your async tests as follows:

```
var tskPlayers = context.Players.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

var tskPlayersNt = context.Players.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.TeamId == teamId).ToListAsync();

var tskTeamsNt = context.Teams.AsNoTracking().Include(x => x.Players).Where(x => x.SportId == sportId).ToListAsync();

Task.WhenAll(tskPlayers, tskPlayersNt, tskTeamsNt);
```

You will see better results.

Answer (score 0):

Async methods imply more IL code, thus explaining those differences for one-shot calls.

You could gain benefits of async methods if you make other async calls in your method.

Another interesting article : https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/analysis-of-entity-framework-6-async-performance/

Comment: Tests are run multiple times.