# Poor performance when loading entity with large string property using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Given an entity and a DbContext like the following:

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string LargeString {get;set;}
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Entity> Entities {get;set;}
}
```

And an entity stored in the database with `Id` 42 and `LargeString` containing some two megabytes of XML.  The following takes half a minute or so, and occasionally gives `OutOfMemoryException`:

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
    var entity = await dbContext.Entities.SingleAsync(e => e.Id == 42);
}
```

At the same time, the following Dapper query executes in miliseconds:

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
    var entity = await dbContext.Database.Connection
        .Query<Entity>("SELECT Id, LargeString FROM Entities WHERE Id = 42")
        .SingleAsync();
}
```

Is it possible to somehow hint Entity Framework that the `LargeString` property could be this large (in a way that would make Entity Framework perform acceptable in this scenario).

Comment: try `dbContext.Entities.AsNoTracking().Single(e => e.Id == 42);` if that fixes let me know

Comment: Good suggestion, I'll try that and get back to you :)

Comment: The `AsNoTracking()` does not improve performance significantly.  However, a colleague of mine pointed out that our production code that this question simplifies is asynchronous, and that might be relevant for performance, so I updated the example code to reflect this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue yesterday. What I did find out is that async operations with Entity Framework is broken or at least very slow. Try using the same operations synchronously:

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
    var entity = dbContext.Entities.Single(e => e.Id == 42);
}
```

Also read the post by [rducom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/533686/rducom) here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28619983/7108481