# How to call raw SQL queries in EF 6.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, async-await

I have a simple gridview which I need to bind with a list of users.

In EF.5.0 I could simple write

```
context.Users.Select(emp => new { Name = emp.FirstName, EmailId = emp.EmailId, UserId = emp.UserId }).ToList();
```

However, I don't see the `.ToList()` method anymore in EF6.0

So, I have to write an async query using `ToAsyncList()`. However, not sure why the below code does not work and system goes in endless execution.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var task = LoadData();
    task.Wait();
    GridView1.DataSource = task.Result;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

private async Task<List<User>> LoadData()
{
    List<User> users = null;

    using (var context = new BlogEntities())
    {
        users = await context.Database.SqlQuery<User>("Select * from User", new object[] { }).ToListAsync();
    }

    return users;
}
```

Can anyone please let me know, what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
var users = context.Users.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.User").ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. This one works. but if I use        context.Database.SqlQuery(User.GetType(), "Select * from [User]", new object[] {}).ToListAsync(), the async method does not work .                       I am wondering why ToList() method is not available here and it forces the users to use async.

Comment: `ToListAsync()` does not work or it takes long time to execute?
There is a [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543293/entity-framework-async-operation-takes-ten-times-as-long-to-complete) regarding this method