# Performance issue with unitOfwork

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, design-patterns, unit-of-work

I have implemented a unitOfwork pattern that let me handle all the process of consulting the db, but I have been getting some perfomace issues. 
ex.

```
public Task<IEnumerable<BooksQueryResult>> GetBooks(int idBook, string Title, string Author)
{
   List<SqlParameter> sqlParams = new List<SqlParameter>();
        sqlParams.Add(new SqlParameter("idBook", queryParams.IdBook?? SqlString.Null));
        sqlParams.Add(new SqlParameter("Title", queryParams.Title?? SqlString.Null));
sqlParams.Add(new SqlParameter("Author", queryParams.Author?? SqlString.Null));


        return repos.DbSqlQueryAsync("EXEC usp_getValidBooks @IdBook, @Title, @Author, @DisclosurePeriod
                                               , sqlParams.ToArray());
}
```

It is supposed to return more than 20k records, but it takes almost 4 min.

Thanks

Comment: And what is the code of `usp_getValidBooks `?

Comment: It is an sql query that takes 3s in running, I also checked the store procedure perfomance. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this performance could be due to using Async method.

Async method can have performance issue when reading a large column from the server (such as varbinary(MAX), varchar(MAX), nvarchar(MAX) or XML).

You can find *rducom* answer which explains in detail the issue with async method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28619983/304832)

Comment: Excellent recommendation!