# C# SqlDataReader ReadAsync() takes 8s vs Read() 2ms on large varbinary

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, sqldatareader

I don't know what I might have done to cause this, but a  `await reader.ReadAsync()` is taking 8000 ms, compared to 2ms if I replace `ReadAsync()` with `Read()` in the same method

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
{
    conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    await conn.OpenAsync();

    string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE order_id = @OrderId";

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@OrderId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = id;

        using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
        {
            if (!reader.HasRows) return null;

            await reader.ReadAsync();
            return (byte[])reader["image"];
        }
     }
 }
```

Removed some of the method for readability

The varbinary in question is about 11MB in size. The actual query execution is still fast, it's just the read that's incredibly slow. Smaller varbinaries are fine.

The `image` column is a FILESTREAM

Comment: is anything running concurrently at the same time, how did you test your subject's statement? also change: `await Task.FromResult((byte[])reader["image"]);` to just `return reader["image"]);`

Comment: I used breakpoint in debugger initially, then a stopwatch which I output the result of

There is a long running task in the background that is checking an API and saving various records to this same SQL database periodically, but even when that's idle this read still takes a long time.

Comment: Not to skirt the issue but do you really need `async`/`await`? This is *generally* only useful if you want to scale the number of concurrent threads like with a web application.

Comment: Ooh, I remember this one. There's indeed a performance regression bug in reading binary blobs with the async methods, and there's a question on that on this very SO. Now, if only I could find it...

Comment: It's a wcf service @Igor

Comment: Try `cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehaviour.SequentialAccess)` (copied from possible duplicate)

Comment: @Igor: no, but I do think it's describing the same issue.

Comment: Entire method down to 139ms with SequentialAccess! I also forgot to mention, the `image` column is a filestream. I'll edit my Q. Thanks @Igor

Comment: Glad it worked. As the cause and solution can be found in that other question I am going to mark this as a duplicate. Feel free to upvote the accepted answer in the dupe.

Comment: I was thinking of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28543293/4137916), which has a very similar analysis (and also mentions `SequentialAccess`). The bug (in that case) is EF not using that automatically.