# From an async method, is calling a LINQ query's ToList, instead of ToListAsync, a potential deadlock?

Tags: c#, async-await, deadlock

I've got a situation where I need to have a *single* LINQ query run non-asynchronously. Reason: There is currently still a bug in how async EF calls load large blobs (more info on that [Entity Framework async operation takes ten times as long to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543293/entity-framework-async-operation-takes-ten-times-as-long-to-complete))

So my options to fix the above bug are to either convert the query to a custom DbCommand and run raw SQL asynchronously, *OR* I can just change the call from `ToListAsync` to a `ToList`.

**TLDR** --- **Question:**
I know that calling asynchronous code synchronously can cause a deadlock (e.g. `query.ToListAsync().Result`), however, does calling the non-asynchronous version of ToList inside of an asynchronous method have the same issue?

Comment: List<T> will hold every object inside it , a large List<T> will consume large memory. I recomend you IQueryable are typically streaming and they are consumed like IEnumerable and they don’t need to hold all the elements they return in memory. To use a ToList inside an async method you have to use Task.Run(() =>) and Task.Wait(); other wise will note complete the task

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know that calling asynchronous code synchronously can cause a deadlock (e.g. `query.ToListAsync().Result`), however, does calling the non-asynchronous version of `ToList` inside of an asynchronous method have the same issue?

Calling a synchronous method like `ToList()` blocks the current thread regardless of whether you do it inside a method that is meant to be asynchronous. So it won't deadlock but it will block the calling method. And you don't expect an asynchronous to block. Remember that an `async` method runs synchronously like any other method until it hits an `await`.

Answer (score 3):

You can keep the async await signature without compiler warnings if you use

```
return await Task.FromResult(query.ToList());
```

Comment: `await Task.FromResult(query.ToList())` is the same as `query.ToList()` without the overhead.