# DbSet property of type class returns null

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I'm creating an API for an app. The DbContext I have trouble with looks like this:

```
public class SchoolPlannerDbContext : DbContext
{
    public SchoolPlannerDbContext(DbContextOptions<SchoolPlannerDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
    public DbSet<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }

}
```

The Activity class is as follows:

```
public class Activity
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Room Room { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Subject Subject { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Group Group { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Slot { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Day { get; set; }
    }
```

All the other properties contain an int ID and a string Name.

My controller looks like this:

```
public class SqlPlannerData : ISchoolPlannerData
    {
        private readonly SchoolPlannerDbContext db;

        public SqlPlannerData(SchoolPlannerDbContext db)
        {
            this.db = db;
        }
        public IEnumerable<Activity> GetActivities()
        {
            return db.Activities;
        }
        public IEnumerable<Group> GetGroups()
        {
            return db.Groups;            
        }
   }
```

GetGroups() works as intended and returns an IEnumerable with properties set correctly.

My problem is that when I'm trying to access db.Activities, the properties of type, say, Teacher (non-basic types like int) are set to null:
[Debugger screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjsiU.png).

However, there is a row in the database that [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJTOW.png). I.e. the columns exist in the database.

What do I do to make GetActivities() return an IEnumerable with correctly set properties?

Comment: Related entities are not loaded by default.  Read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/

Comment: `db.Activities.Include(it => it.Teacher).Include(it => it.Room).ToListAsync()` and so on for other related entities

Comment: **1)** [When to use Include() with Entity Framework?](https://entityframework.net/when-to-use-include) **2)** [Why EF Async Methods are Slow](https://entityframework.net/why-ef-async-methods-are-slow) **3)** [Entity Framework async operation takes ten times as long to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28543293/6630084)

Comment: @Jackdaw both links seem quite old. I doubt it (slow async) would still happen with EF Core. It might even be an issue related to SqlServer driver.

Comment: @abdusco: Hopefully this bug has been fixed in the EF Core or maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

Some properties are null because of lazy loading you need to include them

```
    return db.Activities
             .Include(i => i.Teacher)
              .Include(i => i.Room)
            .Include(i => i.Subject)
              .Include(i => i.Group)
                   .ToList()
```

Each propety Id can be configured by EF5+ as shadows. But I usually prefer to add all Ids explicitely.  This way I have much less problem when I am using db context in the project. But is is optional and you can leave it  as is

```
public class Activity
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int?  TeacherId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int? RoomId  { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public  int? SubjectId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int? GroupId { get; set; }


        public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; }

       
        public virtual Room Room { get; set; }

     
        public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }

       
        public  virtual Group Group { get; set; }

       
        [Required]
        public int Slot { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Day { get; set; }
    }
```

and in order to get list activities  you have to add ToList() or ToArray() at least

```
 public IEnumerable<Activity> GetActivities()
        {
            return db.Activities.ToArray();
        }
```

and by the way, you can' t using not nullabe Id as required becaue it is relevant

```
 [Required]
 public int  TeacherId { get; set; }
```

since int by default is 0 and it is a valid value and required will not be working

Comment: Not what OP asks for. He/she asks why some properties are null.

Comment: The answer to the OP's question was already covered in the comments /w missing eager loading. The contents in this answer around requiring the FKs in the class definition are incorrect and misleading.  EF can resolve FKs provided the naming follows a recognized convention. (Not my general recommendation either, but it's not related to the root of the issue the OP is facing)

Comment: @StevePy Thank you very much for your advise. I appreciate it. I've updated my answer. It will be very kiind of you to take another look and let me know if is acceptable now or still not.