# Getting varbinary data EF Core taking too long

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework-core

I have these two models which are mapped to SQL tables using EF Core code first:

```
public class Profile
{
 public int ID { get; set; }
 public string FirstName { get; set; }
 public string LastName { get; set; }
 public IEnumerable<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
 // Other props
}

public class Attachment
{
 public int ID { get; set; }
 public int ProfileId { get; set; }
 public Profile Profile { get; set; }
 public string FileName { get; set; }
 public byte[] BinaryContent { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to fetch these data like this:

```
 var profileWithAttachments = await _context.Profiles.Include(x => x.Attachments)
                        .Where(x => x.ID == profileId)
                        .ToListAsync();
```

It takes too long to load for example a query which returns about **80 rows**, each of them containing  varbinary data to about **100kb** takes about **30 seconds**. Important to know is that executing this query on SQL Server takes only **2 seconds**! I also have tried using **Dapper** or plain **ADO.NET** but same results. The issue normally seems to be the **BinaryContent** column because if I exclude this column it takes less than a second.
Are there any solutions to these problem or just saving to the file system or blob storage is the only way to go probably?

Comment: Include the SQL query you executed to determine it takes 2 seconds?

Comment: Yes exactly only 2 seconds, I inspected the generated sql and executed it.

Comment: May well be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28619983/4137916) (old issue, but apparently [still not fixed](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/issues/88) since it's a tough thing to do and resides in the bowels of the ADO.NET classes, so EF has only limited blame).