# EF ToListAsync(); blocks when sort by id

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I'm trying to use toListAsync(), but when I use toListAsync it blocks when I try to sort by id. If I sort by companyId it works. The queries that are generated only differ in the field that is to be sorted.
Why does it work by companyId and not by id which is a primary key?

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Document>> SelectAsync(int companyId, int take, int skip)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var context = contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
            {
                var query = (
                    from document in context.DocumentSet
                    where document.CompanyId == companyId
                    select document);

                query = query
                    .OrderByDescending(document => document.Id)
                    .Skip(skip)
                    .Take(take);

                var x = await query.ToListAsync();
                return x;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw ExceptionHandler.Handle(logger, exception,
                $"Error on {nameof(SelectAsync)} for " +
                $"{nameof(companyId)} = {companyId}, " +
                $"{nameof(take)} = {take}, " +
                $"{nameof(skip)} = {skip}");
        }
    }
```

If i change to sort by company, it works.

```
query = query.OrderByDescending(document => document.CompanyId)
.Skip(skip)
.Take(take);


namespace EInvoice.DataLayer
{
   public class Document
  {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public int CompanyId { get; set; }
       public int DocumentStatusId { get; set; }
       public string Content { get; set; }
    }
}

    namespace EInvoice.DataLayer
    {
    public class EInvoiceContext : DbContext, IEInvoiceContext
     {
       public EInvoiceContext(DbContextOptions<EInvoiceContext>   
  options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Company> CompanySet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Account> AccountSet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ExternalAccount> ExternalAccountSet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> UserSet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SentDocument> SentDocumentSet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Document> DocumentSet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DocumentStatus> DocumentStatusSet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FTDocument> FTDocumentSet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ExternalAccountCompany> ExternalAccountCompanySet { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        new CompanyBinder(modelBuilder).Bind();
        new AccountBinder(modelBuilder).Bind();
        new ExternalAccountBinder(modelBuilder).Bind();
        new UserBinder(modelBuilder).Bind();
        new DocumentBinder(modelBuilder).Bind();
        new DocumentStatusBinder(modelBuilder).Bind();
        new FTDocumentBinder(modelBuilder).Bind();
        new SentDocumentBinder(modelBuilder).Bind();
        new ExternalAccountCompanyBinder(modelBuilder).Bind();
    }
}
```

}

Querys on debug view:

```
--Query order by id
DECLARE @__companyId_0 int = 2;
DECLARE @__p_1 int = 0;
DECLARE @__p_2 int = 10;

SELECT [d].[Id], [d].[CompanyId], [d].[Content], [d].[DocumentStatusId]
FROM [Document] AS [d]
WHERE [d].[CompanyId] = @__companyId_0
ORDER BY [d].[Id] DESC
OFFSET @__p_1 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_2 ROWS ONLY

--Query order by companyId

DECLARE @__companyId_0 int = 2;
DECLARE @__p_1 int = 0;
DECLARE @__p_2 int = 10;

SELECT [d].[Id], [d].[CompanyId], [d].[Content], [d].[DocumentStatusId]
FROM [Document] AS [d]
WHERE [d].[CompanyId] = @__companyId_0
ORDER BY [d].[CompanyId] DESC
OFFSET @__p_1 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_2 ROWS ONLY
```

Script to create table:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Document](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[CompanyId] [int] NOT NULL,
[DocumentStatusId] [int] NOT NULL,
[Content] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Document] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, 
OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Document]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT 
[FK_Document_Company] FOREIGN KEY([CompanyId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Company] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Document] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Document_Company]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Document]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT 
[FK_Document_DocumentStatus] FOREIGN KEY([DocumentStatusId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[DocumentStatus] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Document] CHECK CONSTRAINT 
[FK_Document_DocumentStatus]
GO
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Execute the queries directly against it using the native IDE. Compare execution plans if available. Check the statistics if available.

Comment: Isn't the query returning all records having the same `companyId`?  Ordering by that field wouldn't really do anything then.

Comment: What do you mean by `it blocks`? Do you mean a sql deadlock? Are you sure it is not a deadlock in the code? You can use sql profiler to see what is hitting the sql server and what is returned and how long it takes. You can use the debugger on your IDE to see where the code execution is hanging.

Comment: I wanted to say deadlock, that is, if I do it by companyId I get a return if I do it by ID I get a deadlock. If i execute the querys on SQL SERVER i get values in both queries.

Comment: Does it also deadlock when you run those queries in SSMS?

Comment: @igor I have results.

Comment: I take that to mean that in SSMS everything works as expected. I would attach the Sql Profiler and run your code to see what is being communicated. You can then take the prepared sql statement (if that is the failure point) and replace it in SSMS. That can yield a different result than the parameterized query you have in your question.

Comment: It may be you have an inefficient query plan being used. Try running "DBCC FREEPROCCACHE" in your database, then run your examples again. Also, to be sure there aren't any conflicting locks or such try to ensure that nothing else is running against that database that might be locking Documents while testing. Your schema looks fine, the first thing I was checking was that your clustered index didn't accidentally get removed. (I did encounter a production system where someone's brainchild was to replace keys and wiped all the clustered indexes... :)

Comment: Your second query is doing a `.Count()` not a `.ToListAsync()`. Either you captured some other query from another process or your code under test had changed.

Comment: @StevePy sorry, I put the query wrong. When I change the query to sort by Id, in the IDE 'when I debug it doesn't advance "hang" more than the line " var x = await query.ToListAsync();" and in the sql profiler nothing appears no query.

Comment: So if you sort by ID, there isn't even a query picked up by your profiler? If that is the case it isn't a deadlock but rather sounding like something in EF not composing a query to run. Are there any exceptions being thrown if you put a `try`/`catch` around the call?  Also, please update your question to include the actual Entity definition for Document as well as any configuration. (EntityTypeConfiguration or OnModelCreating in the DbContext for that entity).. It may help if catching exceptions to temporarily change it to a syncronous query /w `ToList()` rather than the async variant.

Comment: No exception is thrown, it just gets stuck in ToListAsync() and doesn't go from there. If I use Tolist() I get a return.
I don't understand why it doesn't work when I put the ToListAsync() with id, but changing the ToListAsync to FirstOrDefaultAsync there already works and returns values "var x = await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();"

Comment: Instead of calling `ToListAsync()` call `ToList()`. That will help figure out if there is a deadlock due to async/await which can occur in some conditions. If that works then you need to look at your call stack and make sure you are using async/await all the way down. If it does not work then it could be your mapping with EF or something db specific.

Comment: What do you see if you pause the debugger and disable "just my code"? Does the framework stop in some CPU heavy code? Or are you awaiting async IO?

Comment: Blind shot without having a look at the execution plan, but you might try adding an index on `Document(CompanyId, Id)` or maybe just plain `Document(CompanyId)` to see if that makes a difference in the scope and number of locks you are getting. That would allow SQL to both filter on CompanyID and sort by Id before accessing (and locking) the selected rows in the main table (clustered index).

Comment: I finally found the problem. To solve my problem I can't use TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY] in table creation, toListAsync() doesn't like that. [https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/28543293/entity-framework-async-operation-takes-ten-times-as-long-to-complete] [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543293/entity-framework-async-operation-takes-ten-times-as-long-to-complete]

Comment: @AndreForte - Thank you for the update. The link you included in your comment is actually a copy of a [so] question. It's from one of those scraper sites that tries to make money off of other legit sites. I have included the [so] question as a marked duplicate. If you have additional questions or issues please update your question and I can always remove the duplicate or you can open a new question if it turns out there are additional/other problems.