Minimal API with Entity Framework Core - bad performance due to images in the database
I'm coding an API for a ASP.NET Core v8 Minimal API, with Entity Framework Core. One of the endpoints is supposed to get all items in a specific Items Group. These items are in two tables where the main table is for basic info, and the other table is like an archive where I store images in, the images are stored in raw format.
Here is my code for loading the data:
static async Task<IResult> GetItemsByGroup(Pico2024Context db, string GroupGuid)
{
    return TypedResults.Ok(
        await db.Tbl007s
        .Select(itm => new 
        {
            itm.CardGuide, 
            itm.CardCode, 
            itm.ProductName, 
            itm.Barcode, 
            itm.GroupGuid,
            itm.CardImage,
            MainImage = itm.Tbl152s.Select(itm => new {
                itm.CardImage,
            }).FirstOrDefault()
        })
        .Where(srch => srch.GroupGuid.ToString() == GroupGuid)
        .OrderBy(ord => ord.ProductName).ToListAsync()
    );
}

Tbl007 is the main table, and Tbl152 is the related table.
The problem
When I run the code it takes almost 6 minutes to get 300 records, knowing that among those 300, only 10 records have images in the related table.
What I've tried:

Lazy loading proxy service
Eager loading (.Include())
AsNoTracking() extension


Avoid Async! Well known issue...

@ErikEJ, same issue, takes ages to load. lol!

Maybe you are missing an index??

What is the EF version? What DBMS? How big are the images?

can you try moving the Where clause before your select? Also are you using code-first or database-first?

@AlexanderPetrov
EF: v 8.0.7
DBMS: SQL Server Express, 2014
Images are not that big (avg. 2-3 mbs)

@JerdineSabio Code-First, tried moving the where clause, didn't work.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/28543293/5045688 - Here is a detailed description of why you need to get rid of async.

Did you try splitting query and fetching more data lazily? I mean, cut out "haeavy part", so don't include image at first, and lazy load it.

Use Guid groupGuid instead of string GroupGuid. And remove .ToString() in Where.

@AlexanderPetrov, I believe converting the guid to a string is mandatory, otherwise it will give me an error. Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Guid' and 'string'

@MichałTurczyn Can you please elaborate with an example?

I would try to convert group back from string to Guid and make filtering method like this: .Where(srch => srch.GroupGuid == GroupGuid). Use strong types - C# is not javascript.

@MohammadRadwan That could make big difference, srch.GroupGuid.ToString() == GroupGuid is not a sargable expression.

@GertArnold We can't tell if a C#/Linq expression is SARGable or not because Linq's query translation could identify String/GUID comparisons and generate GUID/GUID comparisons in the actual SQL.

@Dai Sure we can tell if a LINQ expression is sargable or not. Look at the generated SQL: it isn't.

@Dai "That QA is 10 years old, and the accepted answer is for EF6 - not EF Core. It isn't relevant here." Actually it is. According to this relatively recently added answer, the issue is present in EF Core 6.0, so most likely it is still present in EF Core 7.0 and 8.0 as well.

@IvanStoev Ooog :(

Problem solved!!!. It turns out that using raw images is a very bad practice. So I had to create my own CDN. Instead of using a raw images, I used the image URL from the CDN, the performance was way much better.
Here is the code after the changes:
static async Task<IResult> GetItemsByGroup(Pico2024Context db, string GroupGuid)
{
    return TypedResults.Ok(
        await db.Tbl007s
        .Select(itm => new 
        {
            itm.CardGuide, 
            itm.CardCode, 
            itm.ProductName, 
            itm.Barcode, 
            itm.GroupGuid,
            itm.ImageUrl,
            MainImage = itm.Tbl152s.Select(itm => new {
                itm.ImageUrl,
            }).FirstOrDefault()
        })
        .Where(srch => srch.GroupGuid.ToString() == GroupGuid)
        .OrderBy(ord => ord.ProductName).ToListAsync()
    );
}

