# Should I use regular SQL instead of an ORM to reduce bandwith usage and fetching time?

Tags: python, django, orm, ethereum

I'm building a ethereum explorer for fun with django ORM (never used it before).
here is a part of my schema :

```
class AddressModel(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    first_seen = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    addr = models.CharField(max_length=42, db_index=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    is_contract = models.BooleanField()
    is_token = models.BooleanField()
    is_wallet = models.BooleanField()

class BlockModel(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)

    number = models.BigIntegerField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)

    epoch_proposal = models.IntegerField()
    slot_proposal = models.IntegerField()

    fee_recipient = models.ForeignKey(AddressModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    block_reward = models.BigIntegerField()
    total_difficulty = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    size = models.IntegerField()

    gas_used = models.BigIntegerField()
    gas_limit = models.BigIntegerField()
    base_fee_per_gas = models.BigIntegerField()
    burnt_fee = models.BigIntegerField()
    extra_data = models.TextField()

    hash = models.CharField(max_length=66)
    parent_hash = models.CharField(max_length=66)
    state_root = models.CharField(max_length=66)
    withdrawal_root = models.CharField(max_length=66)
    Nonce = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    # you can do address_model_instance.transactionmodel_set.objects.all() since there is a FK in Transaction model

class TransactionModel(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    hash = models.CharField(max_length=66)
    block = models.ForeignKey(BlockModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    from_addr = models.ForeignKey('AddressModel', related_name='from_addr', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    to_addr = models.ForeignKey('AddressModel', related_name='to_addr', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    input = models.TextField()
    is_valid = models.BooleanField()
```

What concerns me here is that if I want to retrieve every `transaction` related to a specific `from_addr` it will also retrieve the bloc data in the returned object, if the `from_addr` has 10K transaction that is 10K `block` data that I don't need.
with regular SQL I would only get a `block_id` if I did a `select *`.

This will lead to useless bandwith usage and take more time to request since it will have to do some `select` operations on the `block` table.

Is this a use case where I shouldn't use an ORM?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is ORM slow? Does it matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699792/is-orm-slow-does-it-matter)

Comment: @OrenIshShalom i think it does, what I got from it is : an ORM slows down everything and server hardware is cheaper than a programmer, but in my case the programmer is free (me) and server hardware is not

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you should use ORM but specifically choose which fields (and which relationships) you want to get.
For example for SQLalchemy you can see [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/data_select.html) how to choose which fields to select, and [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/data_select.html#explicit-from-clauses-and-joins) you can see some strategic regarding the relationships.
Since ORM "hide" some of the implementation parts, it is important to analyze the queries your application actually does, because it might cause performance implications (both bandwith, but also missing indexes etc.)

Comment: I think I'm going to go with well crafted pure SQL queries, reverse engineering the ORM in order to try to enhence it's performance seems counter productive